# What is the best way to find "bad words" within a specific column in a table (MYSQL)?

Tags: mysql

I have a table of comments in a MySQL database that needs to be scanned for "bad words" so that comments that contain these words are flagged for moderation.

The queries that we use to do this run once a day via cron - but are now exceeding 24 hours to complete a scan to flag questionable comments.

The data is organized into 2 tables:

```
create table comments (id bigint(20) not null primary key auto_increment,
comment varchar(512),
author_id bigint(20) not null,
created_date datetime,
status varchar(1) not null default 'A',
badwords smallint(1) not null default 0);

create table badwords (word varchar(255) not null primary key);
```

Once per day we have a cron that executes and triggers the badword scan using these queries:

```
select group_concat(word SEPARATOR '|') into @badwords from badwords;

update comments a set a.status = 'F', a.badwords = 1 where a.comment REGEXP @badwords;
```

This setup worked GREAT for awhile, however the speed at which it matches has been getting slower and slower over time (as more rows are added to the comments table) and as a result the run time of this query has now exceeded 24 hours (which is totally unacceptable).  The comments table now has more than 400 million rows in it and badwords has about 2000 words in it.

Is there a faster way to find bad entries against the badwords list that anyone has found?

I have tried various things like joins, cursors, etc and haven't come up with a faster way of scanning this data for the badwords.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a `FULLTEXT` index.  Construct the query dynamically each day.  The query should be reasonably fast.

```
SELECT ...
    FROM tbl
    WHERE MATCH(txt_column)
          AGAINST(
              'dam sheet friggin'  -- This part is dynamically built
             IN BOOLEAN MODE)
```

With this approach, you don't even need to limit the search to 'new' entries in the table.  In fact, that may slow down the query.  Also, do not do "chunking" as discussed in my other Answer.

There are many problems with this (and other) approaches --

- o vs O vs 0 vs ... as a way to hide bad words from the search
- FULLTEXT depends on the definition of "word"; so adding adjacent letters or inserting spaces will hid a badword from FULLTEXT.

Comment: I like this as a solution - but I dont think that this approach will work well for what we need to do. Alot of the comments are left by bots (think spam) and what not. so the words are often camouflaged in a variety of ways. Thats why we are using regexp to do matching.

Comment: @MediaGiantDesign - How about both -- Hourly FT for rapid check of many words, plus Daily regexp for trickier ones.

Answer (score 1):

Change your query so that you only scan comments that were created since the last scan. Or in the last 25 hours, to avoid missing some comments due to edge conditions.

That way your runtime will be constant* (and short), instead of growing with the size of the database.

If you really must rescan older comments when the badword list is extended, you can spend 24+ hours on it once a month. Or, at the cost of some added complexity, the monthly test could check against the *new* badwords only. (But do measure how much the runtime is affected by the size of the regex; with a good regex engine it might make little difference.)

(*) well almost constant, since more comments will be added in a 24-hour period as your business grows. But that's a lot better than scanning everything every day.

Comment: that was exactly what I wanted to do as well - however, there is a requirement that was placed on me when I proposed that to my client. Basically, the "badwords" table is added to as well (not regularly but monthly based upon human content reviews) as a result, I am told the entire dataset must be scanned in order to catch and flag old comments that contain new "bad words".

Comment: I was just editing my answer to allow for that. Thanks for making it explicit. (That should  be in the question too.)

Comment: If you implement this via, say, "cron", be aware that you need to make sure that one cron stops before the next starts.  Instead of using corn, simply have a ever-running task that starts over when it finishes.

Answer (score 0):

Your REGEXP approach is reasonably good.  (Yeah, mid-word, etc, problems exist.)

Have a timestamp column in the table.  It indicates when the comment was added *or* modified.  INDEX that column.

Now, instead of a daily job, have a continually running job.  (This avoids stumbling over itself *and* catches badwords sooner.)  The job loops through the table, continuing at the timestamp last seen.  That way, it is only checking recently added/modified items.

When you add to the badword list, crank up a second, similar, job that scans through the entire table once, then quits.  Meanwhile, the other job is catching recent stuff and checking for old and new badwords in them.

When running a long list like that, chunk it up.  This will help avoid interference with other threads.  See http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/deletebig#deleting_in_chunks for how to efficiently break a big table into 1000-row chunks.

Answer (score 0):

So the solution to my problem was derived from the suggestions above coupled with the data from an analysis I ended up doing against the performance of the REGEX engine in MySQL vs other regex engines. I found in the end that the MySQL REGEX engine is actually quite slow in comparison to other engines.

I tested MySQL's regex throughput vs bash vs PHP.

Quite unexpectedly, I found PHP to have the fastest regex engine.

The test was as direct as I could be - in all scenarios I loaded all the regex patterns from the db and selected 1 million rows from the comments table and then "timed" how long it took to scan them for all the varieties of words (as described above) and then issuing update statements against the database as necessary.

MySQL always was responsible for selecting or updating the data.

So for the BASH test, I used the mysql command line to return the results to an SH script, then used the SH to evaluate and then send an update query back to mysql.

I followed the same type of setup using PHP - except I used PDO to handle the "select" of the data and STDIO to handle the update queries.

```
php wordvalidation | mysql ....
```

In my comparison, PHP outperformed all other solutions in processing and updating 1mm rows achieving a sub 2 minute run time while performing all the required comparisons described in my question. (Single threaded CLI script).

Once I made this determination, the rest just fell into place.

1. I setup a cron script that runs every 2 minutes to check for new records (using Alexis's suggestion). It tracks the last id it scanned and uses it to look for new records each time it spawns. This ensure new records are scanned and flagged almost immediately (big improvement over the previous method).
2. I setup a second cron script that also runs every 2 minutes as well, but scans old records in a linear fashion, and tracks an index that resets back to 0 on a daily basis so it can start its process over again. This approach guarantees that the entire list is scanned regularly for new "bad keywords". This is probably way overkill for what was required but under the current setup the entire database can be scanned each day in about a little less than 1/2 the time as it was previously doing it in.

Thank you for your comments and assistance Alexis and Rick James.

Comment: Did you build a single, long, Regexp?  That is likely to make a big difference in the performance.  By avoiding refetching the row again and again, MySQL will speed up a lot; PHP will (assuming a simple array fetch), will speed up only a small amount.